# Using Mods to show something is divisible by 3

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How do you show $5^{2 \cdot 3^k}-5^{3^k}+1$ is divisible by $3$ using mods?

I tried to simplify to $2^{2 \cdot 3^k}-2^{3^k}+1$, but now I am stuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

$5\equiv2\equiv-1$, so   $5^{2\cdot3^k}-5^{3^k}+1\equiv2^{2\cdot3^k}-2^{3^k}+1\equiv(-1)^{2\cdot3^k}-(-1)^{3^{k}}+1\pmod 3 ,$

and remember that $-1$ to an even power is $1$ and to an odd power is $-1$.

Comment: Oh i see thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*A variant*:

\begin{align}
5^{2\cdot 3^k}-5^{3^k}+1&=5^{3^k}\bigl(5^{3^k}-1\bigr)+1\\
&\equiv 5(5-1)+1  &&\text{by Fermat, since 3 is prime}\\
& \equiv -1\cdot 1+1  \mod 3.
\end{align}

Comment: are you saying $5^{3^k}\equiv 5\pmod3$ because $3^k\equiv1\pmod{3-1}$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: I was saying this because $x\mapsto x^{3^k}$ is the $k$-times iterated $x\mapsto x^3$ and $x^3=x$ in $\mathbf F_3$.

Comment: Thanks @Bermard, +$1$